# How do I change the bar width in Cambridge US LaTeX Beamer settings?

Tags: overleaf

I want to change the width of these three bars at the bottom of the beamer page, because the title bar width is not enough. How do I do that in LaTeX?

P.S. I'm using CambridgeUS Theme.

Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have two solutions. The easiest one is to define a `shorttitle` for your presentacion.

```
\title[Inst. Variable Quantil Regression]{Instrumental Variable Quantil Regression}
```

When a `short title` is defined, this is what is shown in your footline, while the long title is shown in your cover. If you don't declare a short title, the long title is shown in footline.

[image]

But if you want to change foot width, you can do it with following code. It's the `infolines` footer definition, where .333 original widths have been adjusted to .25+0.5+0.25.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{footline}
{%
  \leavevmode%
  \hbox{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.25\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{author in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}\insertshortauthor\expandafter\ifblank\expandafter{\beamer@shortinstitute}{}{~~(\insertshortinstitute)}
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.50\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{title in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertshorttitle
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.25\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,leftskip=2ex,rightskip=2ex,sep=0pt]{date in head/foot}%
    \hfill%
    \usebeamerfont{date in head/foot}%
    \insertshortdate{}%
    \hfill%
    \usebeamercolor[fg]{page number in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{page number in head/foot}%
    \usebeamertemplate{page number in head/foot}%
  \end{beamercolorbox}}%
  \vskip0pt%
}
\makeatother

\author{Ludwig Gershwin}
\title{Instrumental Variable Quantil Regression}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
Test
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: it worked perfectly. thanks a lot for your help!!!